# List of items to have a random selection and then be inserted to css - not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am trying to have a list of items be randomly selected and then inserted to the CSS in the view. Essentially, I want a list of steps in which the icon selected is random.  I tried putting a list of icon names in an array and using the sample function. It does not work, and when I checked the source code there was nothing there.

```
<% x= ["icon-link", "icon-bar-chart", "icon-edit", "icon-beaker"].sample %>


        <li class="dark-nav ">
              <i class="<% x %> icon-2x"></i>
              <span>Step 2</span>
          </a>
        </li>
```

I tried also putting it as a method in my model and putting the method name in between the <% %>, but that does not work.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Output the value of `x` using `<%=` in your view:

```
<i class="<%= x %> icon-2x"></i>
```